# zuul ignore header from client, but allow zuul filter addZuulRequestHeader

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

how can I ignore header from client(origin request),for example `user-id`, but in the filter, I set the user-id from oauth, and set it by `addZuulRequestHeader("user-id", "value")`,then the microservice will use.

I use `ignore-headers`,then it will ignore all,even I set the header by zuul filter.How can I only ignore the header from client request, but allow it by zuul added?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a filter as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyHeaderFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return PRE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        final RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        context.addZuulRequestHeader("user-id", "whateverValue");
        return null;
    }
}
```

You could replace the header value as above.

Comment: this is not I want. I want to know some configs about `sensitive-headers` and `ignore-headers`

Comment: You need to provide more detail, then, I'm afraid. Your use case seemed like you need some logic in java, rather than simply handling the issue with configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this for myself and came to the conclusion that the only neat way is to wrap the HttpServletRequest so that the forbidden headers are not returned on the `HttpServletRequest::getHeaderNames` invocation. `ProxyRequestHelper` uses the ignored header set for both the original request header and the ones set with `RequestContext.getCurrentContext().addZuulRequestHeader(headerName, headerValue)` so that's why you can't just use the ignored headers set.

You could override `ProxyRequestHelper` in the various route filters or do this : create a wrapper (make sure `forbiddenHeaders` values are trimmed and lowercased) :

```java
public class ForbiddenHeadersRequestWrapperEnforcer extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
{
    private Set<String> forbiddenHeaders;

    public ForbiddenHeadersRequestWrapperEnforcer(HttpServletRequest request, Set<String> forbiddenHeaders)
    {
        super(request);
        this.forbiddenHeaders = forbiddenHeaders;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames()
    {
        Set<String> headerNames = enumerationToLowercaseSet(super.getHeaderNames());
        headerNames.removeAll(forbiddenHeaders);
        return Collections.enumeration(headerNames);
    }

    private Set<String> enumerationToLowercaseSet(Enumeration<String> enumeration)
    {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            set.add(enumeration.nextElement().toLowerCase());
        }
        return set;
    }
}
```

A simple properties class :

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("zuul")
public class ForbiddenHeadersProperties
{
    private List<String> forbiddenHeaders;

    public List<String> getForbiddenHeaders()
    {
        return forbiddenHeaders;
    }

    public void setForbiddenHeaders(List<String> forbiddenHeaders)
    {
        this.forbiddenHeaders = forbiddenHeaders;
    }
}
```

And use that wrapper in a Zuul filter :

```java
@Component
public class ForbiddenHeaderEnforcerRouteFilter extends ZuulFilter
{
    private Set<String> forbiddenHeaders;

    public ForbiddenHeaderEnforcerRouteFilter(ForbiddenHeadersProperties forbiddenHeadersConfiguration)
    {
        this.forbiddenHeaders = forbiddenHeadersConfiguration.getForbiddenHeaders()
                                                             .stream()
                                                             .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                                             .map(String::trim)
                                                             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder()
    {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType()
    {
        return FilterConstants.ROUTE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException
    {
        RequestContext currentContext = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        currentContext.setRequest(new ForbiddenHeadersRequestWrapperEnforcer(currentContext.getRequest(),
                                                                             forbiddenHeaders));
        return null;
    }
}
```

This way, you can set headers using `RequestContext.getCurrentContext().addZuulRequestHeader(headerName, headerValue)` and those will be sent to the backend but never the one coming from the original request.